# Periodic Boundary Condition for a List

Tags: list-manipulation, python

Please take attention to a list as:

```
data={6,12,5,8};
```

It may be interesting in *Python* if `i=0`, then `data[(i-1)%4]=8` (`%` applies as `Mod`). Because in this language the index of a list's elements initiates from `0` i.e., `data[0]=6`.

Therefore, when I want to access `8*6`, I can write `data[(i-1)%4]*data[i%4]` provided that `i=0`.
If `i=1`, then we access `6*12`.

But it is mysteries for *Mathematica*. Because, the indices initiate from `1` instead of `0`.

Of course, one can say we use  `data[[(i-2)%5]]` in *Mathematica* for showing `8` with `i=1`. But it is problematic when we show `6*12`. Because, `data[[(i-2)%5]]*data[[i%5]]` is wrong for `i=2`.

Really how we can define a periodic boundary condition similar in *Python*?

Comment: use the third argument of `Mod`, e.g, `i = 1;
data[[Mod[i - 1, 4, 1]]] data[[Mod[i, 4, 1]]]`?

Comment: O My God!!! Interesting!!! But I saw the help about Mod. But I cannot understand the role of the last unity in [[i-1,4,1]]

Comment: @Unbelievable that last $1$ is the third argument of Mod, and it is not related to `Part` (`[[ ... ]`). It causes the answer to be offset by one. Pretty much exactly what you were looking for, I would think?

Comment: You are right ...But what is the mathematical interpretation? I just know Mod[2,5]=2,

Comment: Would the identity `Mod[p, q, h] == h + Mod[p - h, q]` help you understand what's going on, then?

Comment: Very good  teaching!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the three-argument form of `Mod`:

```
i = 1;
{data[[Mod[i, 4, 1]]] , data[[Mod[i - 1, 4, 1]]]}
```

> ```
> {6, 8}
> ```

```
{data[[Mod[i, 4, 1]]] , data[[Mod[i + 1, 4, 1]]]}
```

> ```
> {6, 12}
> ```

Compare:

```
Mod[Range[0, 10], 4]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2}
> ```

```
Mod[Range[0, 10], 4, 1]
```

> ```
> {4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2}
> ```

Comment: Then `Mod[0,4,1]=4`. You have LIKE. Even Over Like, Even Over Over Over.....Over Like!!!